# SQLAlchemy & Using shared server connection, but different databases

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a usecase where a given host (DBMS) houses multiple databases, each with an identical schema.

Given an input, it's possible to programmatically discern which database I need to use (same connection/server, different DB)

I'm looking at optimizing connections for a vertically sharded dataset. Ideally, we could just connect to A-F databases, using a shared connection (the only difference is the DB name).

Is this doable with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: For clarity, what I'm looking at doing is optimizing connections for a vertically sharded dataset. Ideally, we could just connect to A-F databases, using a shared connection (the only difference is the DB name). The temp work-around I'm using is just one engine per host/dbname pair

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add clarifying information, rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: Changes made to OP